# How can I compute the following definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{3}{(1+2t)^a} dt $$

With a>1.

Thank you

Comment: What is $a$? And what did you try?

Comment: $$2\int \frac{1}{(1+2t)^a}dt = \int \frac{1}{(1+2t)^a}d(1+2t)$$

Comment: General rule: 'Substitute for the worst thing you see, especially in the denominator' leads you to the substitution $u=2t+1$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=1+2t,$ so that $du=2dt.$
So, the indefinite integral becomes $\int\frac{3}{2u^a}du.$ Pull out the constant $\frac{3}{2}$ to get $\frac{3}{2}\int u^{-a}du.$ The antiderivative is $\frac{3u^{1-a}}{2(1-a)}.$ I suppose you can do the rest. Note that the limits of integration change as you make the substitution. Of course, the antiderivative is not defined when $a=1$, and the integral has to be calculated differently in that case. But, given that $a>1$, the antiderivative I've given is right.